# keyup event ls not being fired if a key is pressed outside of the input field

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to implement the same functionality as the continue button (see example code) but for keyed input

**What I want to happen**

If you click outside of the input field but you are still in the **lightslategray container** and the `enter` key was pressed, then fire the event listener.

**What is happening**

If i try to press `enter` while in the input field the event listener is fired as expected.

If I try to press `enter` outside the unfocused input field but while still in the container with the event listener, nothing happens.

How do I fix this?

**Example code**

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let continueBtn = document.querySelector(".continueBtn");
let input = document.querySelector(".input-field");


// Click event listener
continueBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (input.value != "")
    console.log("Do something after clicking continue");
});

// Keyup event listener
container.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {

  if (event.key === "Enter" && input.value != "")
    console.log("Do something after pressing enter");
});
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background: lightslategray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="input-field" type="text" value="sample text">
  <button class="continueBtn">Continue</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your keyboard is never over a certain area or container. You can basically only capture keyboard events on the window object (or in writable fields like input or text but they also belong to the window) when a keyboard event occurs on the window you could still check if the mouse points over a certain area like the container

Comment: @caramba On sites where there is a div with no input fields that is displaying information. you press `enter` and another div is displayed with more information and so on. Are these event listeners also attached the the window object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyboard events like `keyup` only fires on focusable elements (except `body`, `document` and `window`).

Therefore, for it for work on the grey `div` element (which is not focusable), you need to make it focusable by giving it a [`tabindex` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex):

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let continueBtn = document.querySelector(".continueBtn");
let input = document.querySelector(".input-field");


// Click event listener
continueBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (input.value != "")
    console.log("Do something after clicking continue");
});

// Keyup event listener
container.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter" && input.value != ""){
    console.log("Do something after pressing enter");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background: lightslategray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" tabindex="0">
  <input class="input-field" type="text" value="sample text">
  <button class="continueBtn">Continue</button>
</div>
```

However, there is another problem. When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while focusing on the `input` or `button`, the `keyup` event gets fired too. This is because events get bubbled up the DOM tree, meaning when an element fires an event, all its parent/grandparents will fire the event too.

Do prevent that, you can add a check to only run the code when the `event.target` is the element that you intended it to be:

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let continueBtn = document.querySelector(".continueBtn");
let input = document.querySelector(".input-field");


// Click event listener
continueBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (input.value != "")
    console.log("Do something after clicking continue");
});

// Keyup event listener
container.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.target === container){
    if (event.key === "Enter" && input.value != ""){
      console.log("Do something after pressing enter");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background: lightslategray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" tabindex="0">
  <input class="input-field" type="text" value="sample text">
  <button class="continueBtn">Continue</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe my wording was not as accurate but i wasn't trying to make it focusable.

Comment: @Spanishbeginner As mentioned in the first sentence of the answer, making it focusable is the only way to do it.